# Write VB6 on Visual Studio 2008 without .NET support?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, vb6

I have to continue to support VB6 applications.  I've got both VB6 (Visual Studio 6) installed and Visual Studio 2008 as well.   Can I read and write to VB6 projects while in Visual Studio 2008?   Will it damage or destroy my VB6 application?   It would be very cool if I could free up a lot of space and get rid of Visual Studio 6.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 can't compile VB6 applications. You could use it as a text editor only (though it will offer you the VB.NET IntelliSense, not VB6). However, you need Visual Studio 6 to be able to build your application.

Comment: Thank you.  I was hoping that VS-2008 would be able to detect or I could tweak it such that I could throw a switch.  Thanks for the info anyway!

Comment: You can compile VB6 projects from the command line, so I suppose it's possible you could mangle a Visual Studio project to run the VB6 compiler when you click Build. I can't imagine it would be worth it though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478241/vb6-compilation-from-command-line

Answer (score 5):

The VB6 IDE will coexist along side the Visual Studio 2008 quite happily.

The VB.NET LANGUAGE is related but not compatible with VB6. Conversion between VB6 and VB.NET is problematic. There are a lot of subtle and gross differences between the two making them effectively separate languages.

You need to keep both separate IDES and libraries installed on your computer in order to deal with both languages.

If you need for the two interoperate you can do this by creating COM libraries. Both languages can consume COM Libraries created in the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove VB6 you won't be able to build your VB6 apps? VS2002/3/5/8 doesn't know how to compile VB6 projects.

Comment: thanks.  I was afraid of that.  I'll have to keep it around a while.  My clients arent paying for me to rewrite a working app, not right now at least.