# VB6 compilation from command line

Tags: command-line, vb6, compilation

Anyone knows how to compile a vb6 webclass dll from a command line? I am trying to build a tool for automating version building, but it fails with an 'Compile Error in File '[file name]', Line xxxx : Variable not defined' alert displayed.

Comment: When you say, "it fails" please tell us *exactly* what fails (ie., give us the actual command line you're using). Otherwise everybody has to guess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Known bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190165):

> #### SYMPTOMS
>
> When you use command line arguments to compile a Microsoft Visual Basic project that contains WebClass designers, you may encounter errors.
>
> #### CAUSE
>
> When you use the command line argument /MAKE to compile the application, if the associated .DCA files for the Designers (.DSR) are not in the same directory as the .DSR files, you may encounter errors during the compiling. The .DCA files contain type library information that is necessary to compile the project.
>
> #### RESOLUTION
>
> Use one of the following workarounds to compile the project without errors:
>
> - Open the project in Visual Basic, and make a change in the project. Any change, such as entering a space and then deleting the space in the project, will suffice. Close Visual Basic, and save the changes. This rebuilds the .DCA files for the application in the same directory where the .DSR files are located.
> - Compile the application inside of the Visual Basic Integrated Development Environment (IDE). This also rebuilds the .DCA files for the application.
>
> #### STATUS
>
> Microsoft has confirmed that this is a bug in the Microsoft products that are listed at the beginning of this article...

Comment: Is there any known workaround to make it compile without using IDE?

Comment: @MichalDymel I just used a compiled AutoHotKey script to open VB6 with the file required and compile that one VBP that way. It is not the best option, but it works. Hands off, and it fits into automation...

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you need to CTRL-F5 and see what the compile error is, VB6 will allow you to run in debug while there are still errors that won't make it past the compiler, there is probably something that needs to be resolved. Here's a sample for compiling from the command line from a bat file.

```
set vssdir=c:\_vss\
VB6 /MAKE "%vssdir%Project.vbp" /outdir "%vssdir%testbuild"
```

Comment: Project is compiling fine from IDE - without any error. I use the same method you wrote and get this error. Do you use it to build webclass dll?

Answer (score 0):

Does the code build in the debugger?
Check the help available for the switches by running "vb6.exe /?"
Something like:

```
path_to_vb6_exe /l path_to_my_project_name
```

should work. I'm thinking /l not /m as it's a webclass dll so will be activeX. Whenever I've had errors like the one you describe reported from VB6 run from the command line, it's been 'cos the code wouldn't build.

However it does have a few foibles when run from the command line. I found that if I had custom tabs for user controls set up in the IDE, the compile from the command line would always fail.